# Replace two foreach loops with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a two foreach loops and need to replace with linq to overcome performance issues.

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    foreach (var inneritem in item)
    {
        stringList.Add(inneritem.data1)
    }
}

List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    foreach (var inneritem in item)
    {
        stringList.Add(inneritem.data1)
    }
}
```

data1 string data is added to stringList.

Comment: What makes you think linq is a magical perfomance booster? it will still use loops internally...

Comment: What are you doing with `stringList` after filling it with data?

Comment: Also, did you posted your code twice intentionally or by mistake?

Comment: by mistake it posted twice..sorry for that

Comment: @ZoharPeled I knew linq use loops internally. but thinking for better performance.what can we use do you have any ideas on those.. pls help out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

LINQ will make the code cleaner, not faster. Inserting 1M items in a List will cause 20 reallocations and create 19 big temporary buffers if done carelessly.

Each time a list's internal buffer runs out, the List will create a new buffer twice as large and copy the old data over. The old buffer will remain in memory until the garbage collector runs. This can lead to a *lot* of big temporary buffers in memory and even an OutOfMemoryException if memory becomes so fragmented that .NET's allocator can't find a big enough memory range for a new buffer.

**Cleaning up**

One way is to use LINQ is to use two `from` clauses :

```
var query = from item in list
            from innerItem in item
            select innerItem.data1;
var results=query.ToList();
```

Another way is to use `SelectMany` to flatten a nested enumerable, eg :

```
var results = list.SelectMany(item=>item)
                 .Select(inner=>inner.data1)
                 .ToList();
```

**Performance**

To avoid reallocations, the list should be created in advance with a predefined capacity. The capacity doesn't have to be accurate.

If we expect eg 10K items, we can create a list with a capacity of 10K items and fill it in a loop:

```
var results=new List<string>(10000);
var query = from item in list
            from innerItem in item
            select innerItem.data1;
foreach(var item in query)
{
    results.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: What if you create the list with the constructor ovarload that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter? documentation for it states "Initializes a new instance of the List<T> class that contains elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied." Shouldn't that be the most efficient way?

Comment: @ZoharPeled the constructor would have to know how big the IEnumerable<T> is to construct a big enough buffer up front. That's only possible with containers that implement ICollection<T>, eg arrays and lists. [The constructor's source ](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) shows that it checks to see whether it's an ICollection and if not, it just adds items one by one

Comment: Of course... silly me, I should have thought about looking at the source code. Thanks!